# Returning all relationships for a list of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is quite a general question but to make it more understandable I'll give it a bit of context.

In neo4j I have a series of words (nodes) that are associated with one another. I want to specify a list of nodes and the Cypher query return a list of any relationships between those nodes.

The nodes specified in the list are all guaranteed to have at least one relationship to another node specified in the list.

I created a query to do this and in certain circumstances it works fine - http://console.neo4j.org/?id=s30cbm

Unfortunately, when I add the words 'bark' and 'dog' to the list I get an 'unexpected traversal state encountered' error message. I presume this is because the database cursor has got to the fruit node and then there's no relationship between that and bark, even though there is a relationship from tree to bark. http://console.neo4j.org/?id=258d6g

I'm obviously doing the query slightly wrong and any advice would be appreciated on how I can rectify this.

Comment: must be some sort of a bug. appears between nodes 2 and 6. simpler statement: `START n=node(6), m=node(2) 
MATCH n-[r]-m 
RETURN n`. do you get the same error on server instance or in the web console only?

Comment: Yep, the same thing happens on both the console and server instance (different data but very similar and produces the same error). For now I'm thinking of using "START n=node(1,2,3,4,5,6,7) MATCH n-[r]-(m) RETURN n, r, m" which will return all relationships (in both directions for all the listed nodes, and then filtering them on the client using if(n<m) and if((n is in list) && (m is in list))

Comment: This looks like a bug, have created https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/387 to keep track of it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep an eye on this one. Hopefully once it's fixed it'll be much more efficient than my workaround!

Answer (score 0):

This works in the latest console (your second link), btw, so it looks like they fixed it. Looks like it should be working in 1.9-M04+.